# Converting vector to array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, type-conversion

I'm running `matlab R2008b`, and willing to convert a `vector` to an `array`. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you need precisely ?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, a vector is essentially an array (matrix) of dimensions 1xN (for a row vector) and Nx1 for a column vector. You convert one to the other with a transpose:

```
a=zeros(1,5); % row vector of zeros
a = 1:5; % row vector with numbers 1..5 in it
aCol = a' ; % column vector
aCol2 = a(:); % turns it into a column vector as well...
```

By the way - the "Mat" in "Matlab" stands for "Matrix", not "Mathematics". Everything in Matlab is a matrix... even if it's of dimension 1x1.